# Pulling Joined Table Data Before WHILE

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I am VERY new at MySQL and PHP writing. What I am having problems with is pulling data from specific tables, BEFORE the `while` line. My current code is

```
$query_join_tables  = "SELECT m.*, c.id, c.firstname, c.lastname, 
                        IFNULL(m.system_customer,c.id) AS client_id
                        FROM ... AS m
                        LEFT
                        JOIN ... as c
                        ON m.system_customer = c.id
                        WHERE system_customer=".$clientid."
                        ORDER BY system_id ASC";

$result = mysql_query($query_join_tables);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo "BLA BLA BLA";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    echo "MORE BLA BLA";
```

The problem is when I attempt to pull from the table BEFORE the `while` line it won't pull. If I pull after, it works just fine.

Does not work:

```
echo ".$row['firstname'].";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

Does work:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo ".$row['firstname'].";
```

Also, before mysqli or PDO are mentioned - I cannot do it. I'm writing a module for something that is encrypted and hard coded.

Comment: The `while` is where you assign to `$row`. You can't use a variable before you assign it. That's just common sense.

Comment: Totally slipped my mind on that, but yes. It makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will feel silly. The $row variable has not been given the fetched rows yet. when the line

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
```

is run, that is when ONE row's data is given to $row. Calling $row before this point will only give you a null value.

Each time the while loop starts again, it gets a new row. This is called an ITERATOR. It moves down the list one row at a time until it runs and finds nothing. That is when it will exit the loop.

**EDIT (01/23/2015):** Now that I understand that you actually want to have two loops use the same result. I will show how to reset the iterator.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {Do Stuff}

mysql_data_seek($result, 0);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {Do Stuff}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! It did help! What I did to test it was create a new variable with the exact mysql `SELECT` command. I was able to get it to work the way I want, but is there a way that I can do the same thing without having to select the tables twice?

Comment: your $result is what actually has all of the rows in it. You can reuse it as often as you like. Try var_dump($result).

Comment: Just a side note, please use mysqli instead of mysql. mysql is depricated as of PHP 5.5.0.

http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Comment: Sorry, just noticed your note.

Comment: If I call result anywhere before the `while` line, it won't loop, unless I call the `select` line twice. If I run `var_dump($result)` then the loop works, but it gives me "resource(56) of type (mysql result)"

Comment: If you want it to loop before the loop, make two while loops! Simply put mysql_data_seek($result, 0); between the two loops.

Comment: I will edit my answer as I now understand that you actually WANT to have two loops.

Comment: I don't want 2 loops lol. I have to pull data from both tables in multiple areas though. The original `while` code does exactly what I want, I just want to be able to call data from the 2 tables before the `while` loop. Thank you.

Comment: You will either have to make many loops through your $result throughout your program or create appropriate arrays / variables to hold the data you will need throughout your program during one read of each row in $results. I would assume that going through the data one time to create your own data strategy would be more efficient then going through the $result fully each time you want ANYTHING at all. It really depends on your situation though.

Comment: What I am doing that seems to be working is creating a new variable each time I need something. It's what seems to be working best, anyways. Plus, I can shorten the query if I need rather than pulling everything each time.

Comment: once $result = mysql_query($query_join_tables); is run, you do not access the database again unless you run another mysql_query

Answer (score 0):

The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future. Use mysqli. Try following code.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbname");

$query_join_tables = "SELECT m.*, c.id, c.firstname, c.lastname, 
IFNULL(m.system_customer,c.id) AS client_id
FROM ... AS m
LEFT
JOIN ... as c
ON m.system_customer = c.id
WHERE system_customer=".$clientid."
ORDER BY system_id ASC";

$result = $con->query($query_join_tables);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo $row["firstname"];
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Thank you, but again I cannot use mysqli. I did explain in the original post. "Also, before mysqli or PDO are mentioned - I cannot do it. I'm writing a module for something that is encrypted and hard coded."

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Simply try this. It should work.

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("dbName");

$query_join_tables = "SELECT m.*, c.id, c.firstname, c.lastname, 
IFNULL(m.system_customer,c.id) AS client_id
FROM ... AS m
LEFT
JOIN ... as c
ON m.system_customer = c.id
WHERE system_customer=".$clientid."
ORDER BY system_id ASC";

$result = mysql_query($query_join_tables);
$res = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $res['vBookName'];

mysql_free_result($result);
```